# How to use codestar in a serverless project having a microservice architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-codestar

I'm totally new with  `AWS Serverless`  architecture.

I was  trying to generate the project architecture, and I read about `AWS codestar`  and how it can Easily create new projects using templates for AWS Lambda using  Python (which is my case)

But I didn't know if I should :

- generate one project (the main project ) with `AWS codestar` and then
  I create separate folders for every microservice I have
  (UsersService, ContactService ...etc)

**OR**

- every microservice can be generated via `AWS Codestar` so each
  service is a separate codestar project for my lambdas ?

Maybe it's a very stupid question for some of you, please any help or usefull links are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally your decision over how you deploy, although I feel like the general consensus will be option 2. I'll try to explain why.

Option 1 is what you would call a **Monolith**, this means everything for your app is all in one place. This might initially seem great but has a few limitations which I've detailed below:

- All or nothing deployments, if you update a tiny part of the app you need to deploy everywhere.
- Leads to coupling between unrelated components, generally the design pattern can lead to overlapping changes that can cause breaking changes for other parts of your stack.
- Harder to scale, you generally scale larger chunks (i.e. not search and book independently but everything all together).

You can mitigate against these but it can be a bit of a headache.

The second option leads more towards a **Microservice/Decoupled Architecture**.

Some of the benefits of this method are:

- Only deploy the changes you've made, if the search service changes only deploy that.
- Easier to scale infrastructure to meet specific demand.
- Able to implement functional testing of the component easier.
- Restrict access to users who develop specific components.

Option 2 is your microservice based repository setup, so I would suggest using this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris for this well explained and argumented answer ! It helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I will post this as an answer.

What you are asking about is software architecture question, and whether or not to use a **monorepo** vs a **polyrepo**. You've already made the decision about microservices, so this is not a monolith.

The answer is.... it depends. There is no general consensus. Just do search on monorepo vs polyrepo (or multirepo) and be prepared to go down the rabbit hole.

Being a serverless application should have no bearing on the type of structure you decide on. However, CodeStar may have some limitations that make it more difficult to use a monorepo. I'm using the CDK for that.

Here are a couple of articles to get you started:

https://medium.com/@mattklein123/monorepos-please-dont-e9a279be011b

https://medium.com/@adamhjk/monorepo-please-do-3657e08a4b70

Here is another that pertains directly to serverless applications:

https://lumigo.io/blog/mono-repo-vs-one-per-service/